# Function that captures the elements of a list and uses them as names to create a list-column data frame

Tags: r, purrr, rlang

I have the following data frames

```
d1 <- tibble(condition = c("a", "b"), x = c(1, 1)) %>% group_by(condition)
d2 <- tibble(condition = c("a", "b"), y = c(2, 2)) %>% group_by(condition)
d3 <- tibble(condition = c("a", "b"), z = c(3, 3)) %>% group_by(condition)
```

and I want to build the data frame `d`

```
d1_nest <- d1 %>% nest(.key = d1)
d2_nest <- d2 %>% nest(.key = d2)
d3_nest <- d3 %>% nest(.key = d3)

d <- d1_nest %>% left_join(d2_nest) %>% left_join(d3_nest)
```

and I would like to do that with a function

```
my_fun(list(d1, d2, d3))
```

I started with

```
my_fun <- function(l) {
 l %>% map(nest)
}
```

The problem is that I want to supply the name of the data frames (d1, d2 and d3) in the argument `.key` of nest, but I don't know how to do it.

I guess once I can include the `.key`argument, it should be easy to apply `left_join` using `reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map the dfs with their names. One way to do it is `map2()` but purrr now has `imap()` that gives default names if not existing. Finally, since `.key` is a quasiquoted argument, you need to unquote the name.

```
my_fun <- function(l) {
 imap(l, function(df, name) nest(df, .key = !!name))
}
```